# Jquery .is(':visible') not working on load of page in chrome version 57

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am displaying images in my website using lazy load which uses jquery is visible event before displaying the image. This function is not working only from chrome version 57.

Comment: Is this a bug report? If so: https://bugs.jquery.com.

Comment: I don't see this having anything to do with Google Chrome by any means... have you tried in other browsers? [www.whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This could be anything, from your DOM taking 1picosecond more to be available, from a bug on jQuery, cache problems, bad code, non-valid HTML, CSS, lack of a `$(document).ready()`... I could go on for years! Without showing some code that causes the problem, we can do nothing but speculate.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.is(':visible') will not work on all browser.

If you want to check you can use the below function that will work on all browser

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  isvisible: function() {
    //
    //  This function call this: $("div").isvisible()
    //  Return true if the element is visible
    //  Return false if the element is not visible for our eyes
    //
    if ( $(this).css('display') == 'none' ){
        console.log("this = " + "display:none");
        return false;
    }
    else if( $(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' ){
        console.log("this = " + "visibility:hidden");   
        return false;
    }
    else if( $(this).css('opacity') == '0' ){
        console.log("this = " + "opacity:0");
        return false;
    }   
    else{
        console.log("this = " + "Is Visible");
        return true;
    }
  }  
});
```